# Filter rows in Spark dataframe from the words in RDD

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following commands in spark,

```
data = sqlContext.sql("select column1, column2, column3 from table_name")

words = sc.textFile("words.txt")
```

`words.txt` has a bunch of words and data has three string columns taken from `table_name`.

Now I want to filter out rows in data (spark dataframe) whenever the word pattern of each word from `words.txt` occurs in any of the three columns of data.

For example if `words.txt` has word such as `gon` and if any of the three columns of data contains values as `bygone`, `gone` etc, I want to filter out that row.

I've tried the following:

```
data.filter(~data['column1'].like('%gon%') | data['column2'].like('%gon%') | data['column3'].like('%gon%')).toPandas()
```

This works for one word. But I want to check all the words from the `words.txt` and remove it. Is there a way to do this?

I am new to PySpark. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: If you could  use a regex, you could build a pattern like `(?s)^(?=.*gon)(?=.*tap)(?=.*wrap)` etc. (note this regex works the same in Python and Java) to require the presence of all these words in any string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You can replace `like` with `rlike` here if you want to provide an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You may read the words from the `words.txt`, and build a regex pattern like this:

```
(?s)^(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2)(?=.*word3)
```

etc. where `(?s)` allows `.` to match *any* symbol, `^` matches the string start position and then each `(?=...)` lookahead requires the presence of each word in the string.

So, if you place the regex into a `rx` var, it will look like:

```
data.filter(~data['column1'].rlike(rx) | data['column2'].rlike(rx) | data['column3'].rlike(rx)).toPandas()
```

where the regex pattern is passed to `rlike` method that is similar to `like` but performs a search based on a regex expression.

Comment: How do we pass word1, word2 here?

Comment: Just build it with the string functions into an `rx` variable.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew , i tried your suggestion and Im getting the following error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_get_object_id' when I tried t negate the filter : DELV_all_cleaned_df2 = DELV_all_cleaned_df.filter(~DELV_all_cleaned_df['DELIV_LOC_DESC'].rlike(expr)).. the one without the ~ works